# Different words for getting high

Tags: terminology

*Drunk* is a word used for to describe getting high on alcohol.

Similarly *stoned* is used when you are high on weed.

What other words are there to get high on different things 
i.e. Love, friendship, bond, etc. ?

Comment: Exhilarated, stimulated, elated, enlivened, intoxicated, energized are a few  positive type responses to stimuli.   "Warmed" or "Charmed", "comforted" might be other directions.  "what is love" isn't a question we can answer here and in many ways, that is where your question goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High in the context you have used it is informal.

For a word that means similarly intoxicated but by the agency of love you might use -  infatuated:

***[infatuated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/infatuated)***

> To inspire or possess with a foolish or unreasoning passion, as of
>   love.

-- Dictionary.com

To describe feeling high from friendship, there is no specialist word that I know of, you might modify the word though, for instance:

> Experienced a high the likes of which only friendship could bring... etc.

or if you wanted a shorter phrase, perhaps:

> Platonic high

Bond similarly I know of no specific word, so my suggestion would be you modify the word high, as above.

If you want a more general word, that is less informal than high, you might try:

***[Euphoria](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphoria)***

> Psychology. a feeling of happiness, confidence, or well-being
>   sometimes exaggerated in pathological states as mania.

-- Dictionary.com